# Good-bye mailman.... cryptic crossword clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

This is a cryptic crossword clue...

> Good-bye mailman with new delivery method [2,5]

or at least it is my attempt at a clue. The clue is self-contained and none of the surrounding text is relevant, just the clue itself. Clues will be given if required, but I don't expect they will be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> BY EMAIL, a substring of "good-bye mailman" defined by "new delivery method".

Feedback

> I don't think it's all that common to use "with" to clue substring or insertion like here. "X with Y" is more commonly just "X next to Y".
>
>  Also you probably want to avoid using the word "mail" in the clue in the same sense as in the answer. If it was "Goodbye, ma! I'll ..." or something it could be more rewarding to find the email substring there when the word mail isn't already apparent.

Comment: thanks for the (correct) answer and helpful comments